# Generating html page with css integration through AWK

Tags: html, css, shell, awk

Requirement:
To generate a HTML page with CSS integration through shell script - `awk`

CSS: (mystyles.css)

Shell script command: (generate_html.sh)

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "<head>"}
    {print "<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyles.css" media="screen" />"}
    {print "</head>"}
    {print "<table border="1" style=width:40% solid black >"}
END {print "</table>"}
{print "<tr bgcolor=#bfff80>\n<td>"NR, $0"</td>\n</tr>"}' server_list.txt > server_list.html
```

> Exception: Syntax error for '.' of mystyles.css

```
awk: cmd. line:1:{print "<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyles.css" media="screen" />"} 
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                             ^ syntax error
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: You need to escape the double quotes while you try to print them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> awk: cmd. line:1:{print "<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyles.css" media="screen" />"} 
> awk: cmd. line:1:                                                             ^ syntax error
> ```

**Solution : You have to escape quotes**

It seems your existing code, will put link, head, table and tr tag for each record read by awk, which does not produce html table correctly :

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "<head>"}
    {print "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"mystyles.css\" media=\"screen\" />"}
    {print "</head>"}
    {print "<table border=\"1\" style=\"width:40% solid black\" >"}
    END {print "</table>"}
    {print "<tr bgcolor=\"#bfff80\">\n<td>"NR, $0"</td>\n</tr>"}' server_list.txt
```

**Probably I guess you need below one:**

```
awk '
BEGIN{
        # meta header and loading css
        print "<head>"
        print "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"mystyles.css\" media=\"screen\" />"
        print "</head>"

        # start table
        print "<table border=\"1\" style=\"width:40% solid black\" >"
    }
        # print row and cell
    {
        print "<tr bgcolor=\"#bfff80\">\n<td>"NR, $0"</td>\n</tr>"
    }
END {
        # close table tag
        print "</table>"
    }
    ' server_list.txt
```

**For example with test file**

```
$ cat testfile 
row1
row2
row3
row4
```

**It will output :**

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyles.css" media="screen" />
</head>
<table border="1" style="width:40% solid black" >
<tr bgcolor="#bfff80">
<td>1 row1</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#bfff80">
<td>2 row2</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#bfff80">
<td>3 row3</td>
</tr>
<tr bgcolor="#bfff80">
<td>4 row4</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @Akshay for the rectification. html file got created properly as required. However My requirement is to embed the css stylesheet to html. which is not reflecting properly.  below is my css file content. Can you pls help me here..... .circle-text {
display: table-cell;
height: 200px; /*change this and the width for the size of your initial circle*/
width: 200px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
border-radius: 50%;
/*make it pretty*/
background: #555;
color: #fff;
font: 18px "josefin sans", arial; /*change this for font-size and font-family*/
}

Comment: Hi @MarcLambrichs, I was trying to embed the css file to the html file to be generated through awk command.  please find my css file used. referr to the following link. https://gist.github.com/hmsvigle/a7fbe88de3ff6eac318ac021f5d8d539

Comment: @Himansu you have not used class attribute, please use `class="circle-text"`